# SwipeRefreshLayout & RxAndroid subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) not working

Tags: android, retrofit, swiperefreshlayout, rx-android

I using **SwipeRefreshLayout** to handle pull refresh and using **Retrofit** returns **Observable** to get my data , but **Observable.subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) not working**.

```
private SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener refreshListener
    = new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            apis.getData()
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<BookedClass>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Log.e(TAG,""+(Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()));
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                       ...
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Data data) { {
                       ...
                    }
                }
        }
}
```

Log: false

Is my code wrongs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `subscribeOn` to specify on which Thread you should make your Observable actions. If you want your observers to be notified on a specific thread, you should use `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.